# Combinatorial proof for $n\ge1$ of $3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(2^{n-k})$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I know that we are supposed to look at strings with n entries such that each entry lies in {0,1,2} (a ternary string), but I'm not quite sure where to go from here!

Comment: Try writing the set $$\Big\{(A,B)\in 2^{\{1,...,n\}}\times 2^{\{1,...,n\}}:A\cap B=\emptyset\Big\}$$ as the disjoint union $$\bigcup_{k=0}^n\Big\{(A,B)\in 2^{\{1,...,n\}}\times 2^{\{1,...,n\}}: A\cap B=\emptyset,|A|=k   \Big\}$$

Comment: Might there be a geometric interpretation of this as the number of cells of an n-hypercube? Eg, for a cube: #vertices + #edges+#faces+#’solids’ = 8+12+6+1= 3^3?

Comment: This is just the binomial theorem

Comment: Thinking about this more, given an n-hypercube with vertices over {-1,+1}, every cell’s ‘centre’ is determined by some n-vector over {-1,0,+1} so there are 3^n cells. This formula corresponds to counting the cells by rank (equivalently, the number of 0s in the vector) -how nice!

Answer (score 4):

For the left-hand side, the multiplication principle yields $|\{0,1,2\}|^n=3^n$ strings.  For the right-hand side, condition on the number $k$ of $0$s.  There are $\binom{n}{k}$ choices of $k$ entries for the $0$s and $|\{1,2\}|^{n-k}=2^{n-k}$ choices for the remaining $n-k$ nonzero entries.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try counting the number of ways to sort $n$ people into $3$ groups, where each person must be in exactly one group, in two ways.

**Subhint for the right hand side:**

> Try using casework based on the number of people in one of the groups.

**Remark:** This is the same as the argument you have in mind with strings. Each of the $n$ spots in the string represents a person, and each of $0,1,$ and $2$ represent the group that person would be in.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+2)^n=\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=n}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}$ using the Binomial theorem expansion of $(1+x)^{n}$ using $x=2$.